# how to prevent data losing when selectedNodeChanged event triggered in asp.net Treeview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Each time when pressing tree node then selectegNodeChanged event triggered and page is reloaded.So, i lost some data stored in Dictionary,ArrayList...How to prevent those data losing?

So, I stored those Dictionary and ArrayList as "static".It is now resolved my problem.

Is it good way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Do not use `static`. Try to store these in `ViewState` or `Session` instead.
You can consider `ViewState` if it is not a large amount of data.
`static` will be accessible across `Session` and is not a good practice.

You can create properties and avoid code duplication like shown below.

```
    public ArrayList TreeNodeDataList
    {
        set
        {
            ViewState["TreeNodeDataList"] = value;
        }
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["TreeNodeDataList"] == null)
            {
                return (new ArrayList());
            }
            else
            {
                return (ViewState["TreeNodeDataList"] as ArrayList);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, when you want to re-assign data, read `TreeNodeDataList` property. If count of that `ArrayList` is `0`, fetch from DB, else use it.

Hope I am clear enough.